# Can't fire my npm poststart script b/c start script is to start a node server and won't exit

Tags: node.js, express, npm, npm-scripts

I found my npm poststart script won't run because the start script is to start a node server and won't exit.

Pre/Post hooks for build/test script work as expected b/c those scripts will exit when they finish.

So how can I make poststart script run after I start my server?

I am looking for a workaround here or someone just tells me that is impossible. Because I believe the ⁠⁠⁠⁠poststart⁠⁠⁠⁠ [waits for an exit code](https://seesparkbox.com/foundry/the_magic_behind_npm_scripts) which won’t happen when I start my express server.

The scripts are rather simple, just like these(as an example) :

```
    "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "poststart":"echo start done"
    "test": "echo test",
    "posttest": "echo test done"
  },
```

Comment: show your package.json

Comment: as per my knowledge you echo "start done" and "test done" in your command line right?

Comment: postscript always persistent when you restart your server and it will depend on your code can you tell me your particular use case so I can help you.

Answer (score -1):

Pretty sure you can try doing something like this on poststart

`echo start done & node ./bin/www`

Should start the server once the `echo start done` is done.

Comment: this is not much difference then a prestart script run "echo start done". But this is NOT what I wanted and why I asked the question in the first place. I want to run some script after  ""node ./bin/www"